# Incompatible anonymous Function Signatures in C# using lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

```
// method 1
public void RegisterPlayer(Player player)
{
    var mysealedClass = new GreatSubscription
    {
        player_0 = player,
        Subscription = this
    };

    Subscribe(_registeredPlayers, player, PlayerTypes.Player, mysealedClass.Register);
}

// Method 2
private void Subscribe<T>(CachedSynchronizedDictionary<T, int> subscribers, 
    T subscriber, PlayerTypes type, Func<bool> isRegistered) where T: Player
{
// There is some code here -- intentionally omitted, since it is irrelevant
}

// Method 3
protected virtual bool OnRegisterPlayer(Player myplayer)
{
    return false;
}

// Sealed Class
private sealed class GreatSubscription
{
    public Subscription NewSubscription;
    public Player NewPlayer;

    public bool Register()
    {
        return NewSubscription.OnRegisterPlayer(NewPlayer);
    }
}
```

I want use anonymous method in Method 1  and get rid of the mysealedClass & its references but I am getting the error "Incompatible anonymous Function Signatures" on the `rs` before the lambda . What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be appreciated.

When I write method 1 as follows:

```
// method 1
public void RegisterPlayer(Player player)
{                  
   Subscribe(_registeredPlayers, player, PlayerTypes.Player, rs => this.OnRegisterPlayer(player));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda accepts one parameter, but `isRegistered` is a `Func<bool>`, which takes none. Remove the `rs` parameter:

```
Subscribe(_registeredPlayers, player, PlayerTypes.Player, () => this.OnRegisterPlayer(player));
```

Comment: I'm glad it did. Have a nice day!